# undefined method `encrypted_password=' for #<User:0x007fa414b913a0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, registration, user-registration

I have got this error NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create and i don´t knew how i fixed it. If i try make new regisration, the server loading long time and after this i see this error.

My migration looks like this:

```
class DeviseCreateRegistrationsControllers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:registrations_controllers) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
       #t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""
      t.database_authenticatable :null => false
      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :registrations_controllers, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :registrations_controllers, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :registrations_controllers, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :registrations_controllers, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

my registration controller looks like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""
end
```

and my views/devise/registration/new.html.erb look like this

```
<div class="form-container glassy-bg small-10 small-centered medium-8 large-6 columns">
  <h2>Register</h2>

  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div class="mb1"><%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email", class: "radius" %></div>

    <div class="mb1"><%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Password", class: "radius" %></div>

    <div class="mb1"><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Confirm password", class: "radius" %></div>

    <div><%= f.submit "Let's Go", class: "button" %></div>
  <% end %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks like a mess. `RegistrationsController` should be model `User` instead because it extends ActiveRecord::Base and those lines:

```
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

are also from devise for User model.

Why you have `t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""` in your `RegistrationsController`(actually it should be model I mentioned above) ?

It must be copy paste fault somewhere. Please check the whole project again or re-create new Rails application then install Devise from clean project.